# Avoiding SingleOrDefault null reference exception

Tags: c#, linq

I'm adding parameters to insert information into a database and ran into a a potential null reference exception. By using the `SingleOrDefault` LINQ expression, I thought if an instance had no `Tag` called "Name" the `Tag` would default to a null value. This is true as long as the instance has some sort of `Tag`. If the instance has no tags at all, a null reference exception occurs. It's a rare occurrence, but I still need a better way to handle it. Is there a better way to solve this than catching the exception?

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", runningInstance.Tag.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Key == "Name").Value);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only good way is to reconstruct your query a bit:

```
instance.Tag.Where(t => t.Key == "Name").Select(T => T.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

That will do the trick.

---

### Update:

I suspect your `Tag` property is of type `IDictionary<,>`. In that case, the best option to retrieve a value is:

```
if (instance.Tag.TryGetValue("Name", out TValue value))
{
    // We have the value in the value. :)
}
else
{
    // We don't.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you first check the Tag:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",
runningInstance.Tag==null ? null : runningInstance.Tag.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Key == "Name").Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following very general extension method for this:

```
public static TResult ValueOrDefault<T, TResult>(this T obj, System.Func<T, TResult> getter)
{
    return obj != null ? getter(obj) : default(TResult);
}

public static TResult ValueOrDefault<T, TResult>(this T obj, System.Func<T, TResult> getter, TResult Default)
{
    return obj != null ? getter(obj) : Default;
}
```

and then you call it like this:

```
instance.Tag.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Key == "Name").ValueOrDefault(x => x.Value);
```

In English, this is saying: get the single value from the enumeration.  If that value is non-null, call the specified selector function (x => x.Value) on it and return that value.  If it is null, return the default value for the type (or you can also specify another desired default, if you like).

I like this syntax because it's clear what you want to happen, with the null handling bolted on at the end.

Comment: This will not compile at all, because `TResult` is not a `class`. It pretty easily can be a struct.

Comment: As I have already told you, that wont compile. I see at least two errors.

Comment: @AgentFire: Right, forgot that C# doesn't allow default null optional parameters.  Fixed as updated in the code.

Comment: @AgentFire: I hope you will remove that downvote, now that the compilation errors are fixed.

Comment: Hehe, will you ever check your own code in the IDE? ;) That still won't compile.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I did check it in the IDE and it compiles for me.  What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Still, you could define `Default` as `..., TResult Default = default(TResult))`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37604/discussion-between-joshua-frank-and-agentfire)

Comment: I believe there is no need in that.

Answer (score 0):

In the Model View Control paradim, the model's should do as much processing as possible and contain logic that deals with their internal structure.

I reccomend adding a method to runningInstance, such as GetTag that will check if the object has Tags, and if so return the Tag that has the given key.  This method will do all the error checking needed and will be resuable in any other situation where you need to get a Tag from an instance.

Answer (score 0):

The beaviour of C# is to throw `NullReferenceException` on call like `instance.MethodName()` when `instance` is null.
For extension methods(like `SingleOrDefault`) it's technically possible to write method which won't throw `NullReferenceException` in case of `instance` is null. For example:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string SmartToString(this object instance)
    {
        if(instance == null)return "";
        return instance.ToString()
    }
}
```

Though it's **very** uncommon approach because it's usually it blows mind of guys reading code like this:

```
var instance = null;
// .. several lines later
instance.SmartToString();// why exception is not thrown?? how does this code work at all? ... oh, I see ... that's lame ..
```

**Getting back to your question.**  `SingleOrDefault` is implemented like it should be: if `instance` is null - exception is thrown. That's why you have to make sure `Tag` is not null, by code like:

```
if(runningInstance.Tag != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", runningInstance.Tag.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Key == "Name").Value);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tag is null!");
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I have just seen that the question is a couple of years old, so consider this a new take on the problem for people who end up here.

You can use null conditional operator (?.) that returns a null if the object that you are checking is null and a property value if the object is not null. Available from C# 6.0.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Your example:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", runningInstance.Tag.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Key == "Name")?.Value);
```